# Binding variable across two views to control animation speed change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Background

I'm following the [excellent tutorial](https://www.trailingclosure.com/swiftui-animating-color-changes/) by [Jean-Marc Boullianne](https://www.trailingclosure.com/author/jean-marc/) on animating colour in change in swift. I would like to enhance this example by adding a slider that would allow me to control the animation speed. For that purpose I've defined the relevant UI elements in the *ContentView.swift* and I would like to use the values in the *SplashView.swift* that produces the animation.

### Problem

The value that I'm attempting to pass via slider is disregarded and the animation keeps reproducing with the same default speed.

---

## Code

### `ContentView.swift`

A note: colours are defined in the assets catalogue for the purpose of example any values will do.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    // Color variables for the animation
    var colors: [Color] = [Color("AnimationColor1"),
                           Color("AnimationColor2"),
                           Color("AnimationColor3"),
                           Color("AnimationColor4")]

    @State var index: Int = 0
    @State var progress: CGFloat = 0
    @State var animationDuration: Double = 0.5

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SplashView(animationType: .leftToRight, color: self.colors[self.index])
                .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(color: Color("ShadowColor"), radius: 10, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

            Button(action: {
                self.index = (self.index + 1) % self.colors.count
            }, label: {
                Text("Change Colour")
                    .padding(.top, 20)

            })
            Slider(value: $animationDuration, in: 0.0...1.0)
            Text("Animation duration \(animationDuration)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

### `SplashView.swift`

I understand that I'm using the `@Binding` wrong...

```
//
//  SplashView.swift
//  ColourChange
//
//

import SwiftUI

/**
 Customer observable object

 - Parameter color: The color to store
*/
class ColorStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var color: Color

    init(color: Color) {
        self.color = color
    }
}

struct SplashView: View {

    // This binds value from the slider option of the swift ui view
    @Binding var animationDuration: Double
    // Keeping track of the color: animation defaults as per tutorial
    @State var layers: [(Color, CGFloat)] = [] // New Color & Progress
    var animationType: SplashShape.SplashShapeAnimation
    @State private var prevColor: Color // Background colour
    @ObservedObject var colorStore: ColorStore

    // Those init calls help to deal with the binding problem when the value is called
    init(animationType: SplashShape.SplashShapeAnimation,
         color: Color,
         animationDuration: Binding<Double> = .constant(0.1)) {
        self.animationType = animationType
        self._prevColor = State<Color>(initialValue: color)
        self.colorStore = ColorStore(color: color)
        self._animationDuration = animationDuration
    }

    var body: some View {
        // Need to display each layer as an overlay on the Rectangle inside the body variable
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(self.prevColor) // Current color
            // Displaying each layer on top of another
            .overlay(
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(layers.indices, id: \.self) { xLayer in
                        SplashShape(progress: self.layers[xLayer].1, animationType: self.animationType)
                            .foregroundColor(self.layers[xLayer].0)
                    }
                }
            )
            .onReceive(self.colorStore.$color, perform: { color in
                // Animate color update
                self.layers.append((color, 0))

                // Exclamation mark in variable calling is necessary to faciliate unwrapping
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: self.animationDuration)) {
                    self.layers[self.layers.count - 1].1 = 1.0
                }
            })
    }
}
```

### `SplashShape.swift`

For convenience, I have added `SplashShape.swift` file but that file doesn't differ from the original one available in the tutorial.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SplashShape: Shape {

    public enum SplashShapeAnimation {
        case leftToRight
        case rightToLeft
    }

    var progress: CGFloat   // Will take values between 0 and 1
    var animationType: SplashShapeAnimation

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return progress }
        set { self.progress = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        // We return the correct path after deciding which type of animation is being used
        switch animationType {
        case .leftToRight:
            return leftToRight(rect: rect)
        case .rightToLeft:
            return rightToLeft(rect: rect)
        }
    }

    func leftToRight(rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))  // Top left corner
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * progress, y: 0)) // Top Right
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * progress, y: rect.height)) // Bottom right
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height)) // Bottom Left
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }

    func rightToLeft(rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - (rect.width * progress), y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width - (rect.width * progress), y: rect.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }

}
```

Comment: you just forget to pass `animationDuration` to `SplashView`, it takes default value which is `.constant(0.1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the `animationDuration` in `SlashView` is independent of the `ContentView`'s `animationDuration` (that is bound to the `Slider`).

In other words: in your `ContentView` we do not find the `animationDuration` in the initialization of `SplashView`:

```
SplashView(animationType: .leftToRight, color: self.colors [self.index])
```

should be:

```
SplashView(animationType: .leftToRight, color: self.colors [self.index], animationDuration: $animationDuration)
```

But in reality, if the `animationDuration` variable is never changed in `SplashView`, then it shouldn't be declared with `@Binding`.
In this case you can :

1. Replace (in `SplashView`)

```
@Binding var animationDuration: Double
```

by

```
var animationDuration: Double
```

2. Change your custom `init` :

```
init(animationType: SplashShape.SplashShapeAnimation,
         color: Color,
         animationDuration: Double = 0.1) {
        self.animationType = animationType
        self._prevColor = State<Color>(initialValue: color)
        self.colorStore = ColorStore(color: color)
        self.animationDuration = animationDuration
    }
```

3. Initialize `SplashView`(in `ContentView`), this way :

```
SplashView(animationType: .leftToRight, color: self.colors[self.index], animationDuration: animationDuration)
```